# Python to Control CoppeliaSim correct library (RegularAPI or LegacyApi)

Tags: python, simulator, robotics

I want to use CoppeliaSim with Python. I have tried the sim.py module from the legacyApi. Take as an example min 2:05 of: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TGT7KbP7Dfs
However, I cannot not find documentation of its methods and since it is legacy code I would rather move to a more modern implementation. I want to switch to the Regular API: https://www.coppeliarobotics.com/helpFiles/
The methods are very well documented but I do not find how to import them. What import to I have to do? Do I have to do a pip install? Do I have to download any .py file?

1. Plan A: Use the Regular API. Tell me how to import it. The methods are well documented but I do not know where are those. If possible I would be prefer this approach.
2. Plan B: Use the legacyApi. I already was able to find it and use it. But the methods are not documented.